# content at after youtube iframe not shown

Tags: html, youtube

I want to show youtube video in html. For that i am using iframe. But the content at after  iframe is not showing.

this is my html code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title of the document</title>
</head>

<body>
<p>Content of the document......</p>

<h3>1 Microsoft And Google Collaborate On Angular 2 Framework, TypeScript Language</h3><div><p><span class="embed-youtube"><iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="640" height="390" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLOETEcp3DkCoNnlhE-7fovYvqwVPrRiY7&amp;hl=en_US" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true"/></span></p></div>
<p>END END</p>
</body>

</html>
```

In this code "END END" not showing at after the youtube iframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to close the `iframe` tag properly. Currently you close it
inline, but this is not the correct way. Do:

```
<iframe ..></iframe>
```

Comment: how can add it automatically using php

Comment: In order to answer that I need to see the code responsible for the output.